# I need help understanding the following theorem on cyclic groups.

Tags: group-theory

> If $G = \langle a \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $m$, $m > 1$,
>   and $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then $H = \langle a^k \rangle$
>   for some integer $k$ such that $k$ divides $m$ and $k > 1$.
>
> Proof. If $H = \{e\}$, then $H = \langle a^m \rangle$ . Suppose that
>   $H \not= \{e\}$. Let k be the smallest positive integer such that $a^k
>  \in H$. Then $H = \langle a^k \rangle$. Now there exist integers q and r such that $m =
>  qk + r$, where $0 ≤ r < k$, and $a^r = a^{m−qk} = a^m a^{−qk} =
>  a^{−qk} = ((a^k)^{−1})^q \in H$. The minimality of $k$ implies that $r
>  = 0$. Hence, $m = qk$ and so $k$ divides $m$. Since $H \not= G, k > 1$.

I don't understand what does the assumption that $H = \{e\}$, then $H = \langle a^m \rangle$ actually prove and why do we assume $H \not= \{e\}$? Second, how do we know that $((a^k)^{−1})^q \in H$? Finally, how does $H \not= G$ implies that $k > 1$? Thanks for all your help.

Edit: Never mind answering the second question, I understand that now.

Answer (score 2):

- If $H=\{e\}$ then we can write $H=\langle a^k\rangle$ where $k=m$
- We assume $H\ne\{e\}$ so we can pick an element of $H$ on the form $a^k\ne e$
- $H$ is closed by taking the inverse of an element or the product of an element by itself so $((a^k)^{−1})^q \in H$.

Comment: Why do we need to pick $a^k \not= e$ from $H$?

Comment: We need to prove that $H$ is cyclic so it's generated by an element. We take an element on the form $a^k$ with $k$ is the smallest.

Comment: $G$ is cyclic of order m implies that $b^m=e$ for all $b\in G$. Thus $\langle e\rangle=\langle a^m\rangle$. We are just taking cases. Now assume $H\neq \langle e\rangle$ and continue as above.

Answer (score 1):

You have already all the tools once you know that the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $k\mathbb{Z}$. Doing the proof that way is essentially reproving the same thing. The other needed tools are the homomorphism theorems.

Consider the (surjective) homomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ defined by $\varphi(n)=a^n$. Since $|G|=m$, you know that $\ker\varphi=m\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, $\varphi^{\gets}(H)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $m\mathbb{Z}$, so you can conclude that
$$
\varphi^{\gets}(H)=k\mathbb{Z}
$$
for a unique $k>0$ and that $k\mid m$. Thus
$$
H=\phi^{\to}(\phi^{\gets}(H))=\phi^{\to}(k\mathbb{Z})
$$
and therefore $H=\langle a^k\rangle$ by definition of $\phi$.

(Note: $\phi^\gets$ and $\phi^\to$ denote inverse and direct images of subsets in the codomain and domain respectively.)